# AFNetworking 2.0: is it possible to put pure json in the body of a POST request?

Tags: ios, json, http-post, afnetworking-2

I would like to make the following request from my app:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *requestManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
requestManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [requestManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/json"];
requestManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[requestManager POST:urlString parameters:aParameters constructingBodyWithBlock:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```

Where aParameters is an NSDictionary with the following content:

```
NSDictionary *urlParams = @{@"username" : anUser.userName, @"password" : anUser.password};
```

When I make the request from my app with the user input of "anUsername" and "aPassword" I get the following log for the body in my servlet:

```
--Boundary+5738A89B2C391231
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

aPassword
--Boundary+5738A89B2C391231
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

anUsername
--Boundary+5738A89B2C391231--

multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+5738A89B2C391231
```

I was under the impression that using AFJSONRequestSerializer would send my request in the appropriate format, but as the log shows, it's multipart/form data. It is really hard (for me) to parse this kind of request (I'm parsing it in Java on the server side), so my question is: is it possible to send a json in the body of my request? Something like this:

```
{
    "userName" : "anUsername",
    "password" : "aPassword"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone concerned: Instead of using the `POST:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:success:failure:` method, you should use `POST:parameters:success:failure:`. The former performs a multipart form request, while the latter does url form encoding. Additionally, to send the params in JSON, the `requestSerializer` property of the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` instance should be an instance of `AFJSONRequestSerializer` (by default it is set to `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`)
It is really helpful to browse the implementation file of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` for details, it helped me sort this error out.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to send pure JSON in POST request, just send Parameters dictionary. Here is the sample code that is working for POST Request.

```
+ (void)login:(BOUser *)user responseBlock:(APIRequestResponseBlock)responseBlock {

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-application-id-removed" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-rest-api-key-removed" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
     manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@login", BASE_URL_STRING];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"email": user.username,
                             @"password": user.password};


    [manager POST:URLString parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        responseBlock(nil, FALSE, error);
    }];

}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.